# Is there an implementation of Map where the .containsKey(Object) is only using .equals(Object) to check?

Tags: java, dictionary

I was using HashMap when I realised it was putting duplicate keys. The HashMap keys were of an object type I created which overrides the .equals method. I was hoping that HashMap checks for duplicate keys by .equals method only but apparently not.

Comment: If you override `equals` then you should also override `hashCode`...

Answer (score -1):

The very second I posted this question, I found Java Dictionary, which is exactly what I wanted; implementing only .equals method for checking of keys

**EDIT:** Apparently Dictionary is an abstract class, so I cannot instantiate Dictionary, exactly as mentioned by Luiggi. So it turns out I have no other way but to override the .hashCode method of the key object

Comment: `java.util.Dictionary` is an **abstract** class, and its implementation is `java.util.Hashtable` that similar to `HashMap` makes use of `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: Also, when a class's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) tells you in bold typeface that it's obsolete, do not ignore the warning and try to use it anyway.